# ansible playbook run with play tag gathers facts even that gathering facts set to 'no'

Tags: ansible

Below `ansible-playbook` is run using `ansible-playbook playbook.yml --tags=rancher`

```yaml
- name: instal docker 
  hosts: rancher-server
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes

  roles:
    - role: some_galaxy_role

- name: install rancher 
  hosts: rancher-server
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: install rancher
      debug:
  tags:
    - rancher
```

Only `install rancher` play is selected by `rancher` tag and runs as expected. However fact gathering of the first play `install docker` still runs and takes time. Why and is there a way to avoid it?

Below is the output of the playbook run:

```
PLAY [install docker] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [rancher-server1]
ok: [rancher-server2]


PLAY [install rancher]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put [a tag on the play level](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#adding-tags-to-plays), so, the whole `Instal Docker` play is skipped.

Given:

```yaml
- name: Install Docker
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  tags:
    - docker

  tasks:
    - debug:

- name: Install rancher
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  tags:
    - rancher

  tasks:
    - debug:
```

When run with `--tags rancher`, this yields:

```
PLAY [Install Docker] *********************************************

PLAY [Install rancher] ********************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Hello world!
```

---

On the other hand, please mind that you are not forced to gather **all** the facts, [you can also gather subsets](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#parameter-gather_subset), to speed up plays.

For example, you can use a minimal subset of the facts only:

```yaml
- name: Install Docker
  hosts: localhost
  gather_subset:
    - min

  tasks:
    - debug:
```

Of course, it all just depends what is needed in the `some_galaxy_role` that requires you to gather facts.